# Wiring a Google Home capable light switch

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, smart-switch

I just bought a TP-Link Kasa light switch (the HS200 single pole to be exact).  It has two black wires, a white, and a green.  The switch I want to replace has only black and red. Inside the box, I see there are white and green available.  Can I do this?  If so, please tell me how, or guide me towards where I can find the information.  Really appreciate the help.

[image: My proposed switch location]

Comment: I brightened up the interior of the box so it can be seen more easily.

Comment: Thanks, my answer should be similar to the instructions you got with the unit. Be sure to take pictures of the wiring so you can put it back if something does not work.

Comment: 1) Smart switches like this don't work well in metal boxes like the one you have there, and the TP-Link instructions say not to do it.  If it does work it might work poorly or intermittently.   I have had both success and failure doing this, and it's impossible to predict.  2) Does the old switch have three wires connected to it, all of them either black or red?  Or does it have one black and one red?   Is there another switch in your home that also controls the same lights?

Comment: Can you post a photo that shows the inside of the box more clearly please?

Comment: In addition to the metal box issue I wonder if the Kasa will fit in that box?  Have you checked? Regardless of the wiring ... is there room in the box ?

Answer (score -2):

Did you read the instructions that came with it. Here is my best guess on how to wire it, I do not have one so I can only look at sketches.
A. Turn off the breaker
B. Take pictures in case you have to put it back.
C. Remove the plate and switch.
D. Connect each of the two black wires from the switch to the live wires probably black
E. Connect the Green wire to the ground line (bare or green wire)
F. Connect the White wire to the neutral (white wire)
G. Mount the new switch in the box
H. Put the Wall plate on
I. Turn the breaker on.
J. You should be ready to go

Comment: **Read** the question. "The switch I want to replace has only black and red." *Yet you say* "D. Connect each of the two black wires from the switch to the live wires probably black "

Comment: You also stated " I see there are white and green available" you need those to make the switch work, what did the directions tell you? There are two black wires connect one to the red the other to the black.